# Component don't re-render after redirecting at Reactjs with mobx

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

I made sign up page with mobx store at reactJS.
When I submit after filling in information,
if there is an error, it runs redirect like history.push.
So when I use history.push('/') like home url,
it re-render well.
But when I want to re-render on the same url because of same email check,
it sends to url redirected like history.push('/signup').
Unlike '/', it doesn't rerender. So the ex-email duplicated is left on it.
Since I made a reset of email state on componentwillUnmount,
typed email must be dissapeared like pushing F5.
Could you recommend some solution? Thank you so much!

```
 // In mobx store,

 @action submitSignUp = () => {
    const joinData = {
      userName: this.initialState.register.userName,
      email: this.initialState.register.email,
      password: this.initialState.register.password,
      passwordConfirm: this.initialState.register.passwordConfirm,
    };
    axios
      .post('user/join', joinData)
      .then((response) => {
          if (response.data === true) {
          history.push('/signup'); 
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```